# Angular Http Request Alteration Issue

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

I'm facing a really weird problem that wasted almost a day now.

I have ASP.NET Core Web API as the backend and an Angular front end. I'm invoking the API and it seems to me Angular alters the web api response.

Here's how I print the response from the API in console.

```
return this.http
    .get(environment.basePath +"/api/parentForms/" + parentFormId + "/versions/" + version)
    .pipe(map((x:any)=>{
        console.log(x)
        return x
    }))
```

This is what I see in the console.

[image]

And. This is what API really returns in the network tab. It alters the array content.

[image]

Below's fields array expanded.

[image]

As you can notice the fields array content seems like cached. I even tried changing the response object structure. But angular.http returns the same data set for the array fields.

Can anyone give me an idea why this could be happenning?

Comment: You can use model (interface) instead of the any type. and try to map to the model.

Comment: What version of Angular is this? Are you using any `HttpInterceptor` classes that might be altering the response? Also, if you're not actually mapping the response from inside `map` you should probably use `tap`

Comment: @SanjeevS tried it. still the same result.

Comment: @RTYX Project is Angular version 6. I'm using one interceptor that just appends an access token to the request. It doesn't do any other alterations.

Comment: Are you using `Http` or `HttpClient`?

Comment: @RTYX I'm using `HttpClient`

Comment: I would try making a small `StackBlitz` reproduction or provide more information (where is that being logged, for example, or what does the response look like in the interceptor). Otherwise, no clue.